# Boton deshabilitado se esconde detras de las imagenes en Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, botón

Estoy haciendo un juego del estilo Simon Says en forma de flor, entonces tengo un botón que hace de centro de la flor y con el que iniciamos el juego y los pétalos que son los colores del juego son imágenes.

Mi problema es que quiero que al comenzar el juego clickando ese botón se deshabilite para no poder pulsarlo en mitad de la partida, se deshabilita bien usando:

> button.isEnabled = false

pero se me esconde detrás de las imágenes y no sé que puedo hacer para que se quede quieto en su sitio...

Así se ve cuando esta todo correcto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que pasa cuando lo clickas y se deshabilita:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé cómo hacerlo para no romper el "diseño"...
Me habían comentado de ponerlo "no visible" pero eso también estropea el diseño.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias (:

codigo boton:

```
 val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonStart)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        activateImages(true)
        delay(950) {
            playFlower()                 
            button.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#B8A233"
        android:fontFamily="@font/architects_daughter"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:cornerRadius="150px"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.423" />
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo es el diseño del layout y el código donde lo inhabilitas?

Comment: Lo añado en la pregunta :)

Comment: Una solución simple: crea otro activity sin el botón. Así no tienes que lidiar con ese problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he conseguido arreglarlo, el problema era el orden en el xml
antes tenía el botón arriba donde indico con la flecha y al ponerlo abajo, cuando lo deshabilitas como en la imagen ya no se mueve :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar una vista al frente puedes hacer uso del método [bringToFront()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#animate()), ejemplo:

```
view.bringToFront();
```

> [bringToFront()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#animate()) Cambie el orden z de la vista en el árbol, de modo
> que esté encima de otras vistas hermanas.

también puedes realizarlo usando el "Component Tree" en Android Studio ya que aquí puedes ver la jerarquía de las vistas en el layout.

Abre el layout y selecciona la vista de diseño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el Component Tree puedes visualizar las vistas, y puedes ordenar su jerarquía, en este caso la que este abajo es la que se presentará como principal en tu layout.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No conocía ese método, muchas gracias!!! Lo probaré también para practicar (: